# Mule4# Valid DWL to format graphQL request

Tags: graphql, dataweave, mule4

I want to consumer graphQl API.
I know we need to use http requester to call graphQl.
I need some info on forming mutation request using dwl.
I was trying to hit this service https://www.predic8.de/fruit-shop-graphql
using below

```
%dw2.0
outputapplication/json
---
{
  "query": "mutation(\$input:addCategoryInput!) { addCategory(input:\$input) { name products { name}} }",
  "variables": {
    "input": {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Green Fruits",
      "products": 8
    }
  }
}
```

its throwing bad request
But when using below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  "query": "mutation {  addCategory(id: 6, name: \"Green Fruits\", products: 8) {    name    products {      name    }  }}"
}
```

its working.
I want to use above format. Are both not valid requests.
Please share me your knowledge or guide me to right blog to refer.

Comment: test query in playground using 'query variables' BEFORE coding ... define `$id`, `$name`, `$products` variables separately ... no `input` in API, no chance to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output application/json
---
{
  query: "mutation(\$id:Int!,\$name:String!,\$products:[Int]!) { addCategory(id:\$id, name:\$name, products:\$products) { name products { name } } }",
  variables: {
    id: 6,
    name: "Green Fruits",
    products: [8]
  }
}
```

Your issue would appear to be more with your GraphQL. Products is defined as `[Int]!` in the schema, and you need to pass in the individual arguments - I don't see an `addCategoryInput` defined anywhere in the schema, and `addCategory` is expecting individual arguments.